# Using WLST script how to create DbAdapter EIS Connection Factory (remotely)

Tags: jython, soa, weblogic11g, business-process-management, wlst

I am trying to create Create DbAdapter in Admin Server using WLST sript.

```
def createDbAdapter():
    connect('weblogic', 'welcome1','t3://asdf-pdm:7001')
    edit()

    startEdit()
    planPath = get('/AppDeployments/DbAdapter/PlanPath') 
       #D:\Oracle\Middleware\home_ps2\Oracle_SOA1\soa\connectors\Plan.xml
    appPath = get('/AppDeployments/DbAdapter/SourcePath') 
       # D:/Oracle/Middleware/home_ps2/Oracle_SOA1/soa/connectors/DbAdapter.rar

    wpPlan=loadApplication(appPath, planPath) # got exception here
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

While i am trying to load in to memory **DbAdapter.rar** with **Plan.xml** it throws following  error

```
wls:/base_domain/serverConfig> loadApplication(appPath, planPath)
Loading application from D:/Oracle/Middleware/home_ps2/Oracle_SOA1/soa/connectors/DbAdapter.rar ...
Plan for your application will be written to D:\Oracle\Middleware\home_ps2\Oracle_SOA1\soa\connectors\Plan.xml
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in ?
  File "<iostream>", line 290, in loadApplication
Use dumpStack() to view the full stacktrace
        at weblogic.management.scripting.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:59)
        at weblogic.management.scripting.WLSTUtils.throwWLSTException(WLSTUtils.java:181)
        at weblogic.management.scripting.JSR88DeployHandler.loadApplication(JSR88DeployHandler.java:196)
        at weblogic.management.scripting.WLScriptContext.loadApplication(WLScriptContext.java:787)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

weblogic.management.scripting.ScriptException: weblogic.management.scripting.ScriptException: Error occured while performing loadApplication : Could not read confi
guration. : Exception in AppMerge flows' progression
```

Basically it tries to load those file from the file system where it running, rather where it connected. 
while I am doing the same from the server console (locally) then everything works fine.

**So, at this point i want to know, is it possible to update DbAdapter remotely?**

Answer (score 1):

Suvankar,

There could be path problem for the Plan.xml that using '\' instead of '/'. Please check and revert.

Comment: nope .. I have checked it. Is it technically possible to load DbAdapter.rar in to systems memory from remote?

Comment: DbAdapter can be added through AdminServer. Hope you fixed it... please share the final outcome so that other can benefited

Comment: Sorry I am not able to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I too have faced the same issue looks like loadApplication() doesn't support remote loading of the application into the memory . Strangely it's not mentioned anywhere in the doc

Comment: yes !loadApplication() doesn't support remote loading of the application into the memory.

Comment: So haw can you create a DbAdapter Connection factory from a remote wlst script?

Comment: @Robert3452 It's not possible

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation that it isn't possible. It has left me wondering how I can set up a CI server to remotely setup my DbAdapter Connection factories. I guess I can set up a ssh connection to the admin server, copy all the python scripts, then run WLST from there but that seems very convoluted. I thought this was what WLST remote connection was for :(